# Error while building my server [Route.get() requires a callback function]

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm getting an error while building my server, which I have no idea how to fix. Any idea on how to fix this? Thank you! I'm attaching the server page but also my routes so you can see what I'm doing. The error is also listed below. Thank yo uso much!

Error:
users.post('/register' (req, res) => {
^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Malformed arrow function parameter list

server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const cors= require("cors");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000


app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(cors())
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
  })
)

const mongoURI = ""

mongoose
  .connect(mongoURI, {useNewUrlParser: true})
  .then(() => console.log('Mongodb connected'))
  .catch(err => console.log(err)) 

  const Users = require('./routes/Users')
  app.use('/users', Users)

  app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Server is running on pol.')
  })
```

Here is more code from routes.
routes/Users.js

```
const express = require("express")
const users = express.Router()
const cors = require("cors")
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken")
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt")

const User = require("../models/User")
users.use(cors())

process.env.SECRET_KEY = 'secret'

users.post('/register' (req, res) => {
    const today = new Date();
    const userData = {
        first_name: req.body.first_name,
        last_name: req.body.last_name,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password,
        created: today
    }
    User.findOne({
        email: req.body.email
    })
    .then(user => {
        if(!user) {
            bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10, (err, hash) => {
                userData.password = hash
                User.create(userData)
                .then(user => {
                    res.json({status: user.email + 'registered'})
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    res.send('error: ' + err)
                })
            })
        } else {
            res.json({error: 'User already exists'})
        }
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.send('error:' err)
    })
})

module.export = users
```

Comment: Can you post your `./routes/Users`??

Comment: @Subburaj I've just editted it! :) Thanks for any help

Comment: Means your problem solved???

Comment: @Subburaj not really :/ I just added the routes to my post.

Comment: The error I'm getting now is : users.post('/register' (req, res) => {
                       ^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Malformed arrow function parameter list

Comment: Its a simple typo mistake. Just add `,` as `users.post('/register', (req, res) => {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a simple typo mistake

change

```
users.post('/register' (req, res) => {
```

TO

```
users.post('/register', (req, res) => {
```

Comment: Ahh, thanks for that, I totally missed it. It solved the problem, however, I'm getting again the error /Users/petka/Desktop/react-recipes/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:202
        throw new Error(msg);
        ^

Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Object]. Do you know by any chance, what could be the problem.